# serialized form input or querying

Tags: php, forms, input, querying

i am using php,mysql,jquery. My case is that

step 1 : i generate 10 list items 
step 2 : on click of each item more data about that item is to be displayed

As i can get all the data needed from database for the 10 items in step 1 itself ,should I pass all the data as serialized form input with each list item using ajax for step 2 . 
     OR 
    should i send a minor part through ajax and expand the data by querying for each onclick event?
   Which is the best way to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either way should work it just depends on the amount/ size of the data.

If you think the extra information is too large or that the page is loading too slow, I would go with the second option of 'sending the list items and create them first, then when one is clicked use ajax to get its information'.

If there isn't a lot of information I would use the first option as this will reduce the time for the extra information to load when a user click the list item.

Comment: so do u mean that too much information need not be sent through ajax call . instead we can query it over there . so is it like we should'nt send too much information through ajax call?